# Why did Dumbledore return to Hogwarts on a broom?

Tags: harry-potter

In the end of Philosopher's Stone:

> ‘You got there? You got Hermione’s owl?’
>
> ‘We must have crossed in mid-air. No sooner had I reached
> London than it became clear to me that the place I should be was
> the one I had just left. I arrived just in time to pull Quirrell off
> you –’

This strongly implies Dumbledore flew to Hogwarts. Why? Shouldn't he have used Floo powder or something quicker (apparating right outside Hogwarts)?

In universe answers only please (I suspect the OOU answer is obvious.)

Comment: Dumbledore being able to apparate in and out of Hogwarts is a movie invention. In the books, he still has to fly out of Hogwarts before he can apparate, also, there’s a maximum distance you can apparate, though it’s never explained why you can’t apparate longer distances in multiple smaller steps. Probably, because “magic doesn’t work that way”.

Comment: @Holger I clearly write "apparate outside of Hogwarts" for that reason.

Comment: I’m not a native English speaker. For me, it wasn’t clear that “apparating right outside Hogwarts” meant “go outside Hogwarts, then apparate” rather than “apparating  towards the place outside Hogwarts”. Anyway, my comment also mentioned the distance limit. There’s one point were Voldemort is flying towards Hogwarts until reaching a distance below the limit and he can apparate. And he’s in a hurry, not choosing the slower travel for fun. Whether just apparating two or more times isn’t an option at all or it’s just the lack of logic most Wizards share (as Hermione once put it), is not known.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### He was using a thestral due to personal preference

Out-of-universe, Dumbledore was flying on a broom, because none of the other methods of transportation had been invented yet by the author.

In-universe, this has been retconned to Dumbledore using a thestral, and that this was just because he personally preferred this to apparating.

We see this referred to by Hagrid in book five when introducing the thestrals to the reader.

> ‘No, no, no,’ said Hagrid, chuckling, ‘tha’s jus’ superstition, that is, they aren’ unlucky, they’re dead clever an’ useful! Course, this lot don’ get a lot o’ work, it’s mainly jus’ pullin’ the school carriages unless Dumbledore’s takin’ a long journey an’ don’ want ter Apparate – an’ here’s another couple, look –’
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - Chapter 21 - "The Eye of the Snake"</sub>

This fits with his statement in the first book which hadn't actually specifically mentioned a broom.

Comment: What do you mean *"this has been retconned to Dumbledor using a thestral"*? Is it actually written, somewhere in the books, that Dumbledore used a thestral on that particular occasion? Or is it just your guess? Taking a thestral to the ministry and back does not sound particularly practical; where would the thestral be stabled while Dumbledore is at the ministry? A broom does seem much more convenient for this occasion.

Comment: @Stef you mean just like Harry and friends used Thestrals to fly to the Ministry of Magic in chapter 33 of Order of the Phoenix?

Comment: @Stef - It's an inference I'm making from JKR's decision to include this random line.

Comment: You say it's an inference in your comment, but you state it as a fact in your answer. It's _possible_ he was using a thestral... but he could be also be using a broom, or some other method of airborne transport that we're unfamiliar with or not considering. I don't think it's fair to say that it "has been retconned" as fact since it was never outright stated that Dumbledore exclusively travelled by thestral or did so specifically in this instance.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - I immediately qualify the statement with the exact source quote that I am deriving it from.

Comment: No, you state "this was ... because he personally preferred this to apparating". That's not upheld or even _implied_ by the quote. The only thing we can infer from the quote is that Dumbledore had, in the past, flown thestrals for "long journey[s]", not that he prefers that mode of transport, nor even what qualifies as a "long" journey.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - Not sure you understood my last comment.

Comment: Not sure you understood mine. I'm just pointing out that you state a "fact" which your evidence doesn't support. The wording of the answer implies that this is a given, whereas it's a bit of inference (Dumbledore took a thestral on long journeys at least once in the past) and mostly unsupported conjecture/opinion (that he "prefers" this method of transport, or that in fact he did use this other mode of transport on the date in question.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - And as I said, the statement is qualified by showing the actual source printed verbatim inside the answer itself, so people (such as yourself) can judge the validity of the inference themselves and draw their own conclusions if needed. It's not presented as an undisputed fact.

Comment: Since comments are for for suggesting improvements questions and answers: I'm inclined to agree that evidence offered is not sufficient to support a conclusion that the questioner's original quote was "retconned". If you simply changed your phrasing from "this has been retconned" to something starting like "a possible explanation was included in book five..." I think it would demonstrably improve the answer.